# Modifying images of generated imageViews on button click

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, imageview

I am creating a quiz app and having trouble changing the image which is displayed of a specific imageview that is generated in a for loop.

The following code is responsible for generating the imageviews based on the amount of questions in that specific quiz. It is called in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
var imageView = UIImageView()

func addProgressImages(to view: UIView, count: Int){
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

    for i in 0..<count {
        let spacing: CGFloat = 2
        let tag = i + 888
        let width: CGFloat = screenSize.width/CGFloat(count)
        let height: CGFloat = width
        if let view = view.viewWithTag(tag){
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        let x = spacing + CGFloat(i) * width
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: 100, width: width - spacing, height: height))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "question_progress_empty")
        imageView.tag = tag
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        //print("imageviews displaying")
    }
}
```

I have made an attempt to change some of the images to another image when the user selects an answer to that question with an if statement:

```
    func changeImage() {
    if (optA != questionAns){
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wrong_answer")
        print("opta")
    }else if(optB == questionAns){
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wrong_answer")
        print("optb")
    }else if(optC == questionAns){
        print("optc")
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wrong_answer")
    }else{
        print("if statement not initialised")
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfEBR.jpg - This is the output of the above code
Currently, only the last image will be changed when a user clicks a button.

I need help with modifying the imageview which is related to that specific question, e.g. if question 2 is answered, only that imageview will change while the rest remain unmodified.

Hopefully that explanation made any sense, any input would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: You question is not clear . plz explain it properly

Comment: If you tag each question with similar tag(with some calculation as u have done in case of the imageView)to the imageView, then it would be easy to change the image of the question the student attending that particular question, u have just change the image of that particular question which the student is attending, leaving others unchanged.

Comment: @vivekDas the for loop which is in the addProgressImages() function generates the correct amount of imageviews for a quiz (the amount of questions in that quiz), I am trying to modify the image which correlates to the question the user has just answered, for instance if a user answers question 1, the imageview in position 1 should change to either correct_answer or wrong_answer depending if the user got the question correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you are doing few things wrong.

1. you have taken `UIImageView` as instance variable as below, so after
   creating all the images its holding the reference to the last
   `imageView`.

   var imageView = UIImageView()
2. Make the `var imageView` as local variable and in the `func
   changeImage()` get the proper `imageView` using its tag value then
   try to change its image.

If any doubt plz comment.

How to get the `imageView` back in `changeImage()` check below code.

```
let tag = 888 + (questionNumber - 1)
if let imageView = view.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIImageView {
   // Change imageView's image here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know what you're saying I'm just having a bit of trouble implementing it. So I have removed the `var imageView = UIImageView()` and made it a local variable inside `changeImage()` . I'm not sure how to set the image based off of the tag of the imageview, i'm pretty new to swift

Comment: edited my ans check now how you get back then imageView and change the image

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it working now, I created 2 separate functions `changeCorrectImg()` and `changeIncorrectImg()` , both using the code your provided with separate images in each. Everything is working now, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to create an array of image views:

`var imageViews = [UIImageView]()`

And add your UIImagesViews to that array in your loop:

```
for i in 0..<count {
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    // additional setup...
    imageViews.append(imageView)
}
```

Then, you can later iterate over your array and change the images:

```
for imageView in imageViews {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "wrong_answer")
    // etc.
}
```